# xdebug on xampp on mac el capitan

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

I installed XAMPP 5.6.31 on my mac with el capitan, I can start all the serves, it's ok, but now I had to install xdebug to debug php. I followed all the instructions but when I start the web server, even the php info tells me that it's using the php.ini where I added the zend_extension:

```
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so, i cannot see the xdebug section in the phpinfo....
```

where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @user1142705, any update on this?

Comment: Did this solve your issue @user1142705?

Comment: Hey man did It work?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two `php.ini` files one for command line interface and one for the web server.

Are you sure you added the `xdebug.so` extension to the right `.ini` file?

Use `phpinfo()` via the apache server to determine which `php.ini` is getting loaded.